# Simplify DNF expression

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I was given a test in University. Using the laws of logic algebra, step by step transform the given function into DNF.

[image]

I did the next transform: [image]

So in the end I need to simplify expression. Please explain how can I do it.

Comment: That's a nice question. Maybe try using mathJax in place of text because it can be hard to figure out handwritings

Comment: Thanks, I try to rewrite this block.